# Finding the Determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that:

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
x & a & b \\
x^2 & a^2 & b^2 \\
a+b & x+b & x+a \\
\end{vmatrix} = (b - a)(x-a)(x-b)(x+a+b)
$$

I tried expanding the whole matrix out, but it looks like a total mess. Does anyone have an idea how this could be simplified?

Comment: Have you tried to expand it by cofactors?

Comment: Yep, but it looks like a mess for me. :/

Comment: I mean you can also do it by reducing the matrix to row echelon but you have to make sure you keep up with the sign changes.

Answer (score 5):

Note that:

1. The determinant is a polynomial of degree $3$ in $x$.
2. The coefficient of $x^3$ in this polynomial is equal to $b-a$ (why?).
3. The determinant clearly vanishes for $x=a$ (1st and 2nd column coincide), for $x=b$ (1st and 3rd column) and for $x=-a-b$ (1st and 3rd row).

The conclusion is left for you.

Answer (score 4):

Regard the matrix as a polynomial $f(x)$ in $x$.

Note that $a$ and $b$ are roots, because when you set $x = a$ you get that two of the columns are equal, and ditto for $x = b$.

Note that $- a - b$ is a root, because when you set $x = -a-b$ you get that two of the rows are equal.

So
$$
f(x) = c (x - a) (x - b) (x + a + b)
$$
for some constant $c$.

To compute $c$, note that you obtain $x^{3}$ only from the following term of the expansion with respect to the first column
$$
x^{2} \cdot \begin{vmatrix}a&b\\x+b&x+a\end{vmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Add the first row to the third row and play with the matrix you obtain to get a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Nice observation! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

you can expand the matrix determinant and look for "shortcuts" , my solution :

$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
x & a & b \\
x^2 & a^2 & b^2 \\
a+b & x+b & x+a \\
\end{vmatrix} =
x \begin{vmatrix} 
x & a\\
x^2 & a^2\\
\end{vmatrix}-a\begin{vmatrix} 
x^2 & b^2\\
a+b & x+a\\
\end{vmatrix}+b\begin{vmatrix} 
x^2 & a^2\\
a+b & x+b\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

now just expand the matrices determinant:
$$=x(x^2a^2-ax^2)-a(x^2(x+a)-b^2(a+b))+b(x^2(x+b)-a^2(a+b))=$$

open the brackets:

$$x^3a^2-ax^3-ax^3-a^2x^3-a^2b^2+ab^3+bx^3+x^2b^2-a^3b-a^2b^2=
$$

eliminate opposite sign expressions :
$$
a^3x-b^3x-ax^3+ab^3+bx^3-a^3b=
$$

$$x(a^3-b^3)-x^3(a-b)-ab(a^2-b^3)=$$

extract common divisor : 
$$[b-a](x^3-x(a^2+b^2+ab)+ab(a+b))=$$

$$[b-a](x^3-x((a+b)^2-ab)+ab(a+b))=$$

$$[b-a](x(x^2-(a+b)^2)+ab(x+a+b))=[b-a][x+a+b](x(x-a-b)+ab)=[b-a][x+a+b](x^2-x(a+b)+ab)=[b-a][x+a+b][x-a][x-b].
$$
$$
 \square
$$